# My phone is lost how do I track it?

Tags: google-account, lost-phone

I can't get in to my Google account because I can't remember my password.

I can't get a password changed as it won't send to my Gmail.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have the password to your Gmail saved in your browser on any PCs that you use?

Comment: Also, for a starter, see our [lost-phone tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info).

Answer (score 1):

You can't track or locate your phone without access to your Google account, or unless you have some 3rd party recovery software that you would have had to have installed previously such as [Where's My Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alienmanfc6.wheresmyandroid&hl=en) or [Find My Lost Phone!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsp.android.phonetracker&hl=en). But again, you would have had to have these installed previously to losing the device and not having access to your Google account. There are some ways to push an app and install it remotely, but those require access to your Google account, and if you have that you could just use ADM.

Your best bet is to use [Google's Account Recovery](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/) system and once you have successfully logged into your account then access [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) in an attempt to locate your device.

And just for future reference, if you setup a Google account **ALWAYS** setup the account recovery options or going through the [Security Checkup](https://security.google.com/settings/security/secureaccount) as soon after account creation as possible